# Swiftmailler in yii.?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to integrate swiftmailer in my yii application.But till now I have not succeded.
I have followed  the article at 'http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/swiftmailer/' and have done the following .

```
In Protected/Config/main.php  

    'swiftMailer' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.swiftMailer.lib.swift_required',
                    ),

In contoller Function sitecontroller.php


 $SM = Yii::app()->swiftMailer;
        $mailHost = 'mail.example.com';
        $mailPort = 25; // Optional

    // New transport
       $Transport = $SM->smtpTransport($mailHost, $mailPort);
       $Mailer = $SM->mailer($Transport);


        $Message = $SM
        ->newMessage('My subject')
        ->setFrom(array('sajilgopinath@impulse.com' => 'Hello'))
        ->setTo(array('recipient@example.com' => 'Recipient Name'))
        ->addPart($content, 'text/html')
        ->setBody($plainTextContent);

    // Send mail
    $result = $Mailer->send($Message);
```

And now itsshowing error:

```
 include(swift_required.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Use [this extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/mail/) . it is wrapper class for Swift mailer. Very easy to use.

Answer (score 2):

The article states:

```
'swiftMailer' => array(
'class' => 'ext.swiftMailer.SwiftMailer',
```

),

and NOT

```
 'swiftMailer' => array(
            'class' => 'ext.swiftMailer.lib.swift_required',
                    ),
```

You need to specify the class name assuming you have extracted and moved the swiftMailer folder to protected/extensions

EDIT

The instructions above are valid when you download the yii extension only. If you wish to download swiftmailer from swiftmailer.org then you can do the following:

1. download swiftmailer from swiftmailer.org
2. extract it in your vendors folder (protected/vendor/)
3. place the the following code in the file where you need to call swiftmailer

> ```
> require_once('swift/lib/classes/Swift.php');
> Yii::registerAutoloader(array('Swift','autoload'));
> require_once('swift/lib/swift_init.php');
> ```

Make sure you have the vendor folder in your imports 
Yii::import('application.vendor.*');

Comment: @andreas...its now showing Alias "ext.swiftMailer.SwiftMailer" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable.For your information...i have directly downlaoded it from http://swiftmailer.org/ and not used the yii widget...does it make any diff.

Comment: Yes it does. Donwload the yii extension and follow the instructions in the article. Or download swiftmailer from swiftmailer.org and install it in the vendors folder.

Comment: Do I have to follow the same steps if I do it in later way...i.e downloading directly from swiftmailer.org.

Comment: If you download the extension then you need to follow the steps in the article. If you donwload it from swiftmailer.org you need to follow different steps to use the library in your yii project.